# Printing multiple websites arrays

Tags: php, curl, copy, nodes

Unfortunately, after research I still couldn't find the answer for my issue.
The issue is that I cannot print data from multiple pages. Data is printed only once. Perhaps I am missing silly mistake here, which you could help me find it.

```
$cycles=10;
$listValue=0;


for ($cy = 0; $cy < $cycles; $cy++){

$html = file_get_contents("http://www.website.com/rate/today.aspx?d=02.03.2015&r=". $listValue ."01&c=#");

$dom = new DOMDocument;

@$dom->loadHTML($html);


$tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('td');
$data = array();


while($table = $tables->item($i++))
{
    //stuff
}

foreach($data as $item) 
{
    echo "Rank - " . $item['rank'] . "</br>";

}

$listValue++;
echo $listValue."<br>";
}
```

So basically, I am able to print data only of first page.

Comment: Is this the minimum possible code for the problem to appear? If not, could you make it so? In addition to being a good skill for self-debugging, it will allow others to find the problem more easily when they don't have to look through multiple parts. See [about the MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more information.

Comment: Try curl and present your script as a web browser. But before you do that check is there maybe JSON feed or something...

Answer (score 0):

Declare the collection variable before the first loop `$whatWasCollected = "";`

Assign the collected data to a variable at the end of the first loop & Append to the variable each time.

`$whatWasCollected .= "This is what I want to print..."`

Get rid of the last loop and just echo the complete string.

`echo $whatWasCollected;`

Just a suggestion. Try it out and let me know if it works seem like and interesting question to me.

Comment: Try to simplify the whole process is what im saying. As I look are your code again, I can see that your last loop is fine. I would say try to code it so the application builds up what its supposed to print in memory and prints at the end of the loop rather than trying to run the print function multiple times. so the example I used in my answer would refer to your last loop and echo what you want at the end of all loops

Comment: Yes, I understand what you mean. I tried to do that, but the result that I am getting is the same list only multiple times. Somehow data is fetched only from the first $url. Still trying to work on this issue

Comment: Have you tried to stack all the pages in one `$dom = new DOMDocument;`. Try to declare the DOM before the loop starts

Comment: GOT IT! You were correct, I collected all html in one $dom page and only after started my loop. Perhaps this is not the best way to do it, but - it works for me. THANK YOU

Comment: Glad to help. Its a quick and dirty solution. Sure there is always a better way. Especially to conserve application memory but this way only adds an extra second or 2 to your work day